# How do I get the path from which init.el was loaded?

Tags: emacs

I am looking to create a custom config for emacs to use for Erlang work and I want to refer to my custom EDTS repo as being under the directory from which init.el was loaded. Right now I have this:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs-edts/edts/")
```

But I would rather not hardcode it and refer to it by variable.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking the answer is `(file-name-directory user-init-file)`, but instead see <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>v</kbd> `user-emacs-directory`

Comment: (A nit: Be aware that `user-emacs-directory` does not exist prior to Emacs 23.)

Answer (score 1):

I have the following snippet in my init.el:

```
(setq my-init-dir
    (file-name-directory
        (or load-file-name (buffer-file-name))))
```

This has the advantage of working whether init.el is in your emacs.d directory or not.

Answer (score 0):

I have the following in my init file:

```
(defun my-file-name-basename (s)
  "The directory name, without the final part.

For example:
    (my-file-name-basename \"alpha/beta/gamma\") => \"alpha/beta\""
  (substring (file-name-directory s) 0 -1))


;; Note: Normally, it's not possible to find out the file a specific
;; function is defined in. However, it's possible to save the file
;; name at the time this file was loaded.
(defvar my-load-file-name load-file-name
  "The file name of this file.")


(defun my-start-directory (&optional path)
  "The root directory that contains this module.
When PATH is specified, return the start directory concatenated with PATH.
Otherwise return the directory with a trailing slash."
  ;; Note: Try to figure out where we are, so that we can add the
  ;; subdirectories. `load-file-name' only works when the file is
  ;; loaded. Picking up the file from the symbol works when this is
  ;; evaluated later.
  (let ((file-name (or my-load-file-name
                       (symbol-file 'my-start-directory)
                       ;; Default value. (This is used, for example,
                       ;; when using `eval-buffer' or `eval-region'.)
                       "~/emacs")))
    (let ((start (concat (my-file-name-basename
                          (my-file-name-basename file-name))
                         "/")))
      (if path
          (concat start path)
        start))))
```

In addition to finding out where the file containing the above above code is located (which does not have to be the init file), it provides a convenient way to create paths based on it. For example:

```
(setq custom-file (my-start-directory "init/custom.el"))
```